# How to make canvas responsive using Phaser?

Tags: javascript, css, html5-canvas

I have a empty page with a div where goes the canvas. I tried to make my game responsive, but when I inspect the elements I see the canvas not resized. The canvas isn't responsive. I want that the canvas be resized through the CSS from Phaser. If I do this with pure JavaScript I'll have to scale the mouse position in canvas. So, how to make it responsive?

I tried to do that:

```
var game;

function create() {

    // Scaling options
    game.scale.scaleMode = Phaser.ScaleManager.SHOW_ALL;

    // Have the game centered horizontally
    game.scale.pageAlignHorizontally = true;

    // And vertically
    game.scale.pageAlignVertically = true;

    // Screen size will be set automatically
    game.scale.setScreenSize(true);

}

window.onload = function() {

    // Create game canvas and run some blocks
    game = new Phaser.Game(1280, 720, Phaser.AUTO, 'frame', { create: create });

}
```

Comment: You want to get it full screen right? Because of the 1280, 720

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the width and height of the canvas here is how I do it.
I think this is the *Phaser* solution. Give it a try I never used Phaser.

Your page:

```
var bSize = {
  bWidth: window.innerWidth ||
    root.clientWidth ||
    body.clientWidth,
  bHeight: window.innerHeight ||
    root.clientHeight ||
    body.clientHeight,
};

var game;

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

function create() {

    // Scaling options
    game.scale.scaleMode = Phaser.ScaleManager.SHOW_ALL;

    // Have the game centered horizontally
    game.scale.pageAlignHorizontally = true;

    // And vertically
    game.scale.pageAlignVertically = true;

    // Screen size will be set automatically
    game.scale.setScreenSize(true);
}

window.onload = function() {

    // Create game canvas and run some blocks
    game = new Phaser.Game(
        bSize.bWidth, //is the width of your canvas i guess
        bSize.bHeight, //is the height of your canvas i guess
        Phaser.AUTO, 
        'frame', { create: create });

    canvas.style.position = "fixed";
    canvas.style.left = 0;
    canvas.style.top = 0;  
}
```

I hope it helped you out!